# Why does Spring Data Jpa's composite primary key query findById generate an in query?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

spring boot version 3.2.0

hibernate version 6.3.1.Final

#### jpa entity info

```java
@Data
@IdClass(value = SeasonEntityPrimary.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "seasion")
public class SeasonEntity implements Persistable<SeasonEntityPrimary> {
    @Transient
    private Boolean isNew = false;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "season", nullable = false)
    private Integer season;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "`server`", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String server;

    @Column(name = "season_display", nullable = false)
    private String seasonDisplay;

    @Column(name = "map", nullable = false)
    private String map;

    @Column(name = "boss_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer bossId;

    @Column(name = "start_time", nullable = false)
    private Long startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time", nullable = false)
    private Long endTime;

    @Override
    public SeasonEntityPrimary getId() {
        return SeasonEntityPrimary.create(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }
}
```

#### entity IdClass Info

```java
@Data
public class SeasonEntityPrimary implements Serializable {
    private Integer season;
    private String server;

    public SeasonEntityPrimary() {
    }

    public SeasonEntityPrimary(Integer season, String server) {
        this.season = season;
        this.server = server;
    }

    public static SeasonEntityPrimary create(SeasonEntity entity){
        return new SeasonEntityPrimary(entity.getSeason(),entity.getServer());
    }
}
```

#### Repository Info

```java
@Repository
public interface SeasonRepository extends JpaRepository<SeasonEntity, SeasonEntityPrimary>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SeasonEntity> {
}
```

#### query findById Info

```java
this.seasonRepository.findById(new SeasonEntityPrimary(8,BaServer.CN_BILIBILI.name()));
```

#### view sql

```sql
Hibernate: select se1_0.season,se1_0."server",se1_0.boss_id,se1_0.end_time,se1_0.map,se1_0.season_display,se1_0.start_time from seasion se1_0 where (se1_0.season,se1_0."server") in ((?,?))
```

findById that does not use a composite primary key does not generate an in query

I don't know why Jpa does this, what is the principle?